# How to use the data of DataTable in report viewer?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I get the data source of datagridview as datatable and passed it to the reportviewer

```
        DataTable dd = (DataTable)DGVCars.DataSource;
        dd.TableName = "Cars";
        Report r = new Report(dd);
        r.Show();
```

---

```
       // MaterialsSuppliersDataSet t = new MaterialsSuppliersDataSet();

       // MessageBox.Show("" + dd.Rows[0][1]);

        ReportDataSource RDS = new ReportDataSource("Cars",dd);


        RV.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        LocalReport lc = RV.LocalReport;
        lc.DataSources.Add(RDS);

        RV.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";

        this.RV.RefreshReport();
```

**How can I use the fields of Datatable to display in report ?**

Answer (score 0):

To bind the records to report viewer use Databind.

```
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Report1.rdlc");
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("Cars", Dataset);
this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
this.ReportViewer1.DataBind();
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Kindly refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15597/Using-the-ASP-NET-ReportViewer-in-Local-Mode) codeproject article in details.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1) Add a new class library item in your project.

2) Define Columns of your datatable as properties of this class like bellow example:

```
   String _name;
   Public String name
   {
       get {return _name;}
       set {_name=Value;}
   }
```

3) Build your project.

4) Add a Report Wizard item to your project.

5) Define a datasource with Object type for your new rdlc report and select your class(Which defined in step 1) as dataset.

Now you can see properties of your class(Which are the same with columns of your datatable) as fields in your report.